# Adding css file to html

Tags: html, css, client, chat, cloud9-ide

I'm working on an real-time chat app with MEAN stack , I begin with html and css , and i'm working on cloud9 platforme, my problem is that i can't add the css file to html !! i tried many time to change the path of my css file but still doesn't work for my :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="psirt/client/views/main.css">
```

The path to html file and css file is : 
psirt>client>views>index.ejs which contains the html code
psirt>client>views>main.css for the css file

[image: screenshot of the path]

any help please ? thnx a lot!!

Comment: Per Chris' suggestion, open up your browser console and see what the error is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `/` before the path. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/views/main.css">
```

(if your project root is `psirt`)

Alternatively, just use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

Comment: Inspect your code and see where it tries to open your css file from.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding type of the document to the `link` tag? See the example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="psirt/client/views/main.css">
```

Also, you might want to redefine your drectory for the `href`.

Comment: `type="text/css"` is not necessary for HTML5.

Comment: @Chris Oh, my bad. 

Comment: @Ahmed202: Open the network and check the full URL where your sever is trying to catch the css file

Comment: sorry, but how to do that ?

Comment: Open your browser console and go to the network tab. You will see there all the files that your server is sending to your browser. check for _main.css_ and tell me what is the full path. (Which browser do you use?)

Comment: this is the full path : https://psirt-ahmedmkadem.c9users.io/psirt/client/views/main.css and i use google chrome

Answer (score 1):

inspect your code. I think your framework may set any basepath for your code. So your host calling that link and results in error. But i am not sure about it